# How to combine multiple plots with different x-axis and different y-axis

Tags: matlab

I need to combine multiple plots that have different x-axis and different y-axis but the same dimensions.

For instance:

```
x1 contains  100 values;y1 contains 100 values


x2 contains 100 values;y2 contains 100 values



xn contains 100 values;yn contains 100 values
```

Comment: So what's the problem, _specifically_?

Comment: I don't kow how to plot them at the same time because they have different x-axis and different y-axis?                                                                                                           Apparently, I will use a loop but i don't know how?

Comment: You should add an example of your data, and the plotting code you tried. It would also help a lot if you would add a similar (or a hand-drawn) chart showing the desired result. It is likely that all you need is [`hold on`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html).

Comment: There's documentation for this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/graph-with-multiple-x-axes-and-y-axes.html and also https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
figure;

for  j=1:100

    plot (x(j),y(j));

    hold on;
end

hold off;
```